# Resources to get started with deep reinforcement learning

Tags: neural-networks, references, deep-learning, reinforcement-learning

Assume the learner is proficient with artificial neural networks, and has some background in reinforcement learning. What are some good resources (books/videos/papers/GitHub repo/etc.) to get started with deep reinforcement learning?

Comment: You can check out my github repo which has all the code and explanation https://github.com/sudharsan13296/Hands-On-Reinforcement-Learning-With-Python

Answer (score 6):

A nice introduction deep reinforcement learning  by Lex Fridman (2019-01): https://youtu.be/zR11FLZ-O9M

2 complimentary, easy-to-read blog posts to get started on deep reinforcement learning: the first one focuses on policy gradients, the second one focuses on deep Q-learning.

1. [Deep Reinforcement Learning: Pong from Pixels](http://karpathy.github.io/2016/05/31/rl/) ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20170422232615/http://karpathy.github.io/2016/05/31/rl/)) by Andrej Karpathy (May 31, 2016).
2. [Demystifying Deep Reinforcement Learning](https://www.nervanasys.com/demystifying-deep-reinforcement-learning/) ([mirror](https://www.nervanasys.com/demystifying-deep-reinforcement-learning/)) by  Tambet Matiise on Nervana (December 21, 2015)

Then, two more in-depth resources:

1. 10 videos, ~90 minutes each: [Advanced Topics  2015 (COMPM050/COMPGI13)](http://www0.cs.ucl.ac.uk/staff/d.silver/web/Teaching.html)
    ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20170422233746/http://www0.cs.ucl.ac.uk/staff/d.silver/web/Teaching.html)) on Reinforcement Learning by David Silver (2015)
2. 455-page free  book: [Reinforcement Learning: An Introduction (2nd Edition)](https://web.archive.org/web/20160927020220/http://webdocs.cs.ualberta.ca/~sutton/book/bookdraft2016sep.pdf) by Richard S. Sutton and Andrew G. Barto (2016)

To start coding:

1. [Learning Reinforcement Learning (with Code, Exercises and Solutions)](http://www.wildml.com/2016/10/learning-reinforcement-learning/)
    ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20170422234509/http://www.wildml.com/2016/10/learning-reinforcement-learning/)) by Denny Britz (October 2, 2016)
2. [Minimal and Clean Reinforcement Learning Examples](https://github.com/rlcode/reinforcement-learning) (2017)
3. [Using Keras and Deep Q-Network to Play FlappyBird](https://yanpanlau.github.io/2016/07/10/FlappyBird-Keras.html) ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20170423010049/https://yanpanlau.github.io/2016/07/10/FlappyBird-Keras.html), [code](https://github.com/yanpanlau/Keras-FlappyBird)) by Ben Lau (July 10, 2016) (the code is straightforward to run on Ubuntu)
4. [Using Keras and Deep Deterministic Policy Gradient to play TORCS](https://yanpanlau.github.io/2016/10/11/Torcs-Keras.html) ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20161213122738/https://yanpanlau.github.io/2016/10/11/Torcs-Keras.html), [code](https://github.com/yanpanlau/DDPG-Keras-Torcs)) by Ben Lau (October 11, 2016) (note: installing the `gym_torcs` requirement to have the code run may take some time, and instructions are only given for Linux).

More links:

- [A curated list of resources dedicated to reinforcement learning.](https://github.com/aikorea/awesome-rl)

Answer (score 4):

You can see many resources on github already including [this recent list of Deep RL papers](https://github.com/muupan/deep-reinforcement-learning-papers)

Also checkout some implementations such as [Deep Q learning](https://github.com/nivwusquorum/tensorflow-deepq)

And here is a nice video by David Silver at RLDM [videolectures.net deep RL](http://videolectures.net/rldm2015_silver_reinforcement_learning/)